# force_update in save method

Tags: django-models, django-forms

I have to update an entry in my django model.

I have used force_update in save method like this:

```
register = rform.save(commit=False)
register.user = request.user
register.save(register.user,force_update=True)
```

But it gives me an error:

```
"ValueError at /status/
Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving."
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot update a model instance until it is already there in the database. You should save it to the database first, only then does `force_update` become applicable.

See the documentation [here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects)

Comment: but to make normalized databases what programming language should i use? wtf we have programming languages yet no parent model talks to child tables seriously it's retarded. Not without totally bastardizing the app language